# how to display position number as it is filled in associated products in a GROUP PRODUCT

Tags: frontend, grouped-products, position, associate-products

How to display the POSTION NUMBER as filled in the Associated Products Table, i dont wanna use the Count function, as it gives me Serial Numbering, i want it to display the same number FILLED in the position Coloum.

Comment: I have just figured the way of doing the same.

Comment: add the following '<td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getPosition()) ?></td>' in the line where you want to show the position

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to your own question, possibly with a full code snippet as it could help someone else out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks david, Edit the Group.phtml under /app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/catalog/product/view/type

i have added Ref No (Position), Part Number (SKU), Req(Default Qnty) and made the Qnty as 0 for the Customer, you can edit as per your requirement.

The Code is

```
    <?php $this->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?>
<table class="data-table grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
    <col />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th width="4%" class="a-left"><?php echo $this->__('Ref No.') ?></th>
        <th width="30%" class="a-left"><?php echo $this->__('Part No.') ?></th>
        <th width="44%" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
        <th width="4%" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Req') ?></th>
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                <th width="12%" class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th width="6%" class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php $count = 1;  ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getPosition()) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getSKU()) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?></td>
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
            <td class="a-right">
                <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <td class="a-center">
            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                <input type="text" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*0 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('super-product-table')</script>
```

I am not very good in Magento, but this works great for me as i needed this solution. Good Luck